# nuget.config how to specify NuGet package dependency version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, config

I am trying to make a Visual Studio 2019 project which will automatically download a specific version of a NuGet package, and if a new user opens that project, it will automatically restore/download that version of the package.

I'm trying to acomplish this using a nuget.config file at the base of my VS2019 repo, my nuget.config includes one source (Artifactory),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <clear />
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
    </config>
    <packageSources>
        <!-- When <clear /> is present, previously defined sources are ignored -->
        <!-- Remove this tag or un-comment the nuget.org source below to restore packages from nuget.org -->
        <!-- For more info, see https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file -->
        <clear />
        <add key="Artifactory" value="https://my-artifactory-url/artifactory/api/nuget/ult-testware-nuget" />
    </packageSources>

    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>

    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

But what is the syntax to include a section that specifies the need to download version 1.0.0 of the package "MartinTestPkgXYZ" ? Can I include that in my nuget.config file so the package and version get downloaded when you open or build?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference) can help you?

Comment: You have to use `PackageReference` in your `csproj`, not in `NuGet.config`. And if you want to use the same package version for different projects, use NuGet's [Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management)

Comment: When you build it should automatically restore missing packages: `dotnet build`. Do you need to use the same version in every project - if so see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088045/9971404).